# sed command to double every occurrence of words that contain a substring but not double the word itself

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

My question is with the help of **sed** double every occurrence of words that contain the substring 'two', but do not double the word 'two' itself

What I have tried so far :

```
cat filename | sed 's/ \ (two\) /\1\1/g'
```

But my problem is it is repeating word itself.

For example:

```
two times twothird threetwothree
```

After performing the above sed operation what I got is:

```
twotwo times twotwothird threetwotwothree
```

But what I intend to get here is:

```
two times twothird twothird threetwothree threetwothree
```

Anyone got any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It is 's/    \    ( two  but stackoverflow is just showing /( for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*two[[:alpha:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+two[[:alpha:]]*)/\1 \1/g' file
```

- `[[:alpha:]]*two[[:alpha:]]+` matches all words that have a `two` in the beginning or middle, but not `two` itself
- `[[:alpha:]]+two[[:alpha:]]*` matches all words that have two in the middle or the end, but not `two` itself
- the `()` expression extracts the matching word which is used in the replacement expression `\1 \1`

Example:

```
s="two times twothird two threetwothree onetwo twothree two"
sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*two[[:alpha:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+two[[:alpha:]]*)/\1 \1/g' <<< "$s"
```

yields

```
two times twothird twothird two threetwothree threetwothree onetwo onetwo twothree twothree two
```

Comment: There was an issue with my previous answer which wouldn't have handled words that end with `two` properly.  Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(\S*two\S+|\S+two\S*)/\1 \1/g
```

check for at least one prefix or suffix to "two"